# Built-in MAX function only returns an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, max

I am trying to write a stored procedure ( using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2) to retrieve the maximum measurement value from a table. This seemed like an easy thing to do, so I wrote a short stored procedure to get the MAX. However, when I ran the procedure, it returned a 0 rather than the expected 0.018 value.

When I hover my mouse over the MAX function, it displays "built-in function MAX(expression) RETURNS int". So it seems to be casting my result as an int. This is rather annoying.

I guess I'll have to calculate the maximum the long way unless anyone here has an easier solution. Any ideas?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMaxOscillation] (@SerialNumber varchar (16), @Date datetime)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @MaxOsc DECIMAL(18,6)

    SELECT @MaxOsc = MAX(Value)
    FROM LoadListingOscillations
    WHERE SerialNumber=@SerialNumber AND Date=@Date AND Value IS NOT NULL


    RETURN @MaxOsc

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: MAX() will take the data type of the column it is evaluating.

Comment: What happens when you run the query by itself, without the stored procedure?

Comment: Value is a nullable Decimal(18,6). When I run the query by itself, it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do `MAX(CAST(Value AS DECIMAL(18,6)))`

I am guessing that the `Value` is not a DECIMAL, so you must cast it before the assignment

[Here is the SQLFiddle to prove that if the table is set up as a Decimal then this will work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2dfa/1)

[Here is a SQLFiddle that shows that the cast is needed](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9abaf/8)

**UPDATE**

If `Value` is indeed a Decimal(18,6), then you need to make sure of your table values. Because, as you can see from my examples, this should work

**The last thing that is probably more your problem** is that you are returning an integer. I do not think you can [return anything but an integer in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx). You will have to do a `SELECT @MaxOsc` or use an [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) variable

Comment: Value is a nullable DECIMAL(18,6). I tried casting it like you suggested just in case the nullable part was messing it up, but it still does not work.

Comment: @Lara I updated my answer. The last item is most likely your problem

Comment: I changed the "RETURN @MaxOsc" to "SELECT @MaxOsc" and that worked, thanks.

Comment: @Lara No problem, in case I updated too late, I had forgot that you could also use OUTPUT variables if that works better :)

Comment: Oooh... that works much better. I can't believe I forgot that I could use an output variable.

Answer (score 1):

stored procedures communicate in three ways: the RETURN value, and OUTPUT parameter and a result set

**RETURN VALUE**
if you need to return an integer, you can use this method:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyInt
( @Param int)
AS
DECLARE @ReturnValue int

SELECT @ReturnValue=MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = @Param
RETURN @ReturnValue
GO
```

and now call your procedure like:

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue int
       ,@Param         int
SET @Param=1
EXEC @SelectedValue = GetMyInt @Param
PRINT @SelectedValue
```

this will only work for INTs, because RETURN can only return a single int value and nulls are converted to a zero.

**OUTPUT PARAMETER**
you can use an output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyInt
( @Param     int
 ,@OutValue  int OUTPUT)
AS
SELECT @OutValue=MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = @Param
RETURN 0
GO
```

and now call your procedure like:

```
DECLARE @SelectedValue int
       ,@Param         int
SET @Param=1
EXEC GetMyInt @Param, @SelectedValue OUTPUT
PRINT @SelectedValue
```

Output parameters can only return one value, but can be any data type

**RESULT SET**
for a result set make the procedure like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyInt
( @Param     int)
AS
SELECT MyIntField FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKeyField = @Param
RETURN 0
GO
```

use it like:

```
DECLARE @ResultSet table (SelectedValue int)
DECLARE @Param int
SET @Param=1
INSERT INTO @ResultSet (SelectedValue)
    EXEC GetMyInt @Param
SELECT * FROM @ResultSet
```

result sets can have many rows and many columns of any data type